# How true is the myth of Moola nakshtara effecting Father in law?

Tags: astrology

It been mentioned panchangas that moola nakshatra effects fatehr in law, how true is this? can anyone who has knowledge on the topic guide me

Comment: Just ignore such foolish beliefs..Unfortunately due to such mis beliefs and misconception, even well educated people are hoodwinked. Another way to overcome this i.e. if one believes in this belief, one can get married to a person whose father is no more.

Comment: You should ask an astrologer.I don't think any competent astrologer is browsing this site.

Comment: but my friends parents are not agreeing for marriage just because mine is moola nakshatar 2 pada, and one astrologer has told there is no solution for this problem. Please  help me by any supporting proof if any one has

Comment: @Samyukta Consult astrologer. I think site has no erudite Astrologer.